# `tree` horizontal display

Tags: terminal, directory-structure, tree

Is there an alternative to `tree` command (or some way using the `tree` command itself) to print the directory structure horizontally?

Quite often, I have a tree structure, for which I have to scroll a lot. If it were printed horizontally, no scrolling would be required.

Comment: If you have to scroll "a lot", this implies a large directory structure. How would this fit better horizontally?

Comment: I have just discovered that the world has almost forgotten Martin Schmidt's 1988 `rot` command.

Comment: @Kusalananda : Yes. That makes sense. Actually, what I had in mind was a hybrid display, where the parents are spread horizontally and their children vertically. That would be the optimal display.

Comment: @JdeBP : Can you share some link for the `rot` command?

Comment: @Kusalananda a file structure which is rather deep than broad. Something you can create with `perl -nle 'mkdir $_ and chdir $_ or die' /usr/share/dict/words` (think twice before running that ;-))

Answer (score 1):

As opaquely referenced by @JdeBP above, there's a utility entitled `rot`, available as [a tar.Z file from ugu.com](http://www.ugu.com/pub/unix/sec1/rot.tar.Z).  Similarly transformative as `tac(1)` and `rev(1)` are, `rot(1)` will rotate lines to become columns.

```
$ tree --charset=ascii --noreport | rot -or | sed 's/./& /g; y/`|-/++|/';
. + + + + 
  | | | | 
  | | | | 

  M r r r 
  a o o o 
  k t t t 
  e   . . 
  f   c m 
  i     a 
  l     n 
  e 
$
```

Comment: It won't work for UTF-8 though (the source is older than UTF-8).